# Get language detect with majority of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

With python and a dataframe with one language per row, I am trying to detect the language, using langdetect.

I am trying to define a function that gives back the highest probability language, but for multiple columns.
So if the first column hast a probability of (0.986 en, 0.678 de) and the second (0.986 de, 0.23 en) - it should return "de" because (0.678+0.986)/no. of columns(=2) is the highest

For just one column i already got following code, that gives back the detected language for each input row x:

```py
    def _getLang(self, x): 
        try:
            if not self._isBlank(df):
                return detect(df["col1"])
        except:
            print("Error: ", df["col1"] )
            return ''
```

But how do I proceed for the combination of multiple columns with `detect_langs`?

The data looks similar to this
| col1 | col2 |
| -------- | -------------- |
| The weather is green    | Hello Anna, wie geht es dir?            |
| The sun is shining   | Das Internet ist schlau            |

detect_langs - will give the possible languages with probabilities.
So I need a function that combines the possibilities of col1 and col2 and gives as return the overall language of the row

Thanks for the help and tips

Comment: Does it mean you want to get the highest average value for each language detected for all values on a row? And add the result to a separate column? Could you please share a full test case (at least one row)?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I changed the description.

Comment: Sorry, it is not that clear. Look, the first row is `['The weather is green', 'Hello Anna, wie geht es dir?']` and the `detect_langs` method calculate `[[en:0.999997497655409], [af:0.7187181891086558, nl:0.14285582904323396, de:0.13842589452980678]]`. So, what is the expected result now?

Comment: My problem is on how to calculate detect_langs or better detect for multiple selected columns. So I want to select col1 and col2 and get from these combined the language. So e.g.: if for the first row: col1 gets en: 0.99, de: 0.7398 and for col2 de: 0.9987, en: 0.223 (just random numbers) It should give as output de, because the total probability of de is the highest.

Comment: How did you claculate the total probability?

Comment: with detect.. But it just works for one value

Comment: No, I mean the probablity for the whole row. Sum all `en`, all `de`... and then divide by the number of columns? It would help if you updated the post with an example, you may even use the [values from my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67588667/get-language-detect-with-majority-of-multiple-columns?noredirect=1#comment119474153_67588667).

Comment: Yes exactly divide by the number of columns. It is changed now.